# Can heat transfer occur between two bodies with same temperature and different specific heat capacity?

Tags: thermodynamics

Heat flows between two bodies in contact until the system attains thermal equilibrium. What happens if the bodies in contact having different specific heat capacity and same temperature. Does the flow of heat occurs until the heat energy between the bodies become equal since the amount of heat need to rais the temperature is different?

Comment: Heat is that form of energy which is transferred due to a temperature difference.

Comment: No. Temperature is the correct variable, not heat content. Now, heat will flow between the two bodies - the question is whether there is net heat flow.

Comment: Suppose you had two bodies, one the size of a grape and one the size of an ocean.  Which makes more sense to you:  at equilibrium (a) they should have the same amount of heat or (b) they should have the same temperature?

Comment: @JonCuster right, I agree net heat flow is zero. But at any one moment the heat flow doesn't necessarily have to be zero. I suppose those two statements are true as long as the temperature is not absolute zero.

Comment: @docscience If at any moment the heat flow doesn't necessarily have to be zero, how does the heat know which way to flow?

Comment: @ChesterMiller Not speaking from authority, but rather to my belief, at the quantum scale, it (heat) doesn't know, no more than a neutron 'knows' when to decay. The quantum motion of atomic size particles and the *heat* this motion represents is random. At a larger scale the sum of these motions and associated heat a random walk. And at even a larger scale the so called equilibrium we observe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be an analogy will help. If two tanks containing water are connected by a pipe, water flows from the tank with higher level to that with lower level of water. Temperature is analogous to water level. Heat capacity is analogous to floor area of the tank. The tank with a larger floor area can hold greater amount of water (for a given water level), but that has nothing to with determining whether and in which direction water will flow.

Answer (score 1):

Simply a No.

There are so many ways to reason this. Suppose it's possible and the heat is transferred from object A, to object B, with initial temperature $T_A = T_B = T_o$. With heat transfer alone, $T_A$ decreases and $T_B$ increases.

Since you have two sources with different temperatures, you would be able to build an engine out of it. This, violates the second law of thermal dynamics.

Or simply, when they are of different temperatures, heat transfer will happen until they again reach the same temperature.